# Drawing in the main window from another class with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I need some help because I'm trying to make a Tetris game, as my first project in C++, but I have some problems.

I would like to keep the main window declaration in the main file, and draw on this same window from a class `BoxRenderer` to draw all the Tetrominos, background etc.

But my Sprite doesn't show up, I have a black screen, here's my code:

main.cpp:

```
// SpaceOdyssey.cpp : définit le point d'entrée pour l'application console.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "BoxRenderer.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 280), "Tetris-like by Orionss");
    sf::Texture bgTexture;

    if (!bgTexture.loadFromFile("sprites\\background.png"))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    BoxRenderer renderer(bgTexture);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

        window.clear();
        renderer.render(window);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

BoxRenderer.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BoxRenderer.h"

BoxRenderer::BoxRenderer(sf::Texture bgTexture)
{
    m_bgTexture = bgTexture;
}

void BoxRenderer::render(sf::RenderWindow& win)
{
    m_bgTexture.update(win);
    sf::Sprite background(m_bgTexture);
    win.draw(background);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`void sf::Texture::update(const Window &window)` reference](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Texture.php#ad3cceef238f7d5d2108a98dd38c17fc5):

> Update the texture from the contents of a window.

You are clearing the window just before that, and this overwrites your texture, so it's completely black. You don't want to be calling `m_bgTexture.update(win);` at all.

Comment: it was that ! I didn't really understand the update function so now it's ok. Thank you :)